# ec2 - Do temporary files fill up root ebs volume if there is no ephemeral instance store?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, diskspace

Related to: [How do I add instance storage to an existing Windows EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654174/how-do-i-add-instance-storage-to-an-existing-windows-ec2-instance)

My root 60G ebs volume fill up very quickly, and I can't find the culprit in the file system. My actual files only take up about 10G. I've found out that if I "Stop" and then "Start" the instance, it frees up the remaining 50G.

Note: I started the instance as free micro and then later upgraded to m3.medium. Apparantly micro instances don't have ephemeral storage and you can only add "instance store" upon launching an instance. So I'm thinking I don't have access to ephemeral storage and that it is instead eating up my root ebs volume space with temporary files. Is that possible?

```
#df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       59G   47G   13G  80% /
devtmpfs        1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm


#du -sh  /* | sort -n
0       /proc
0       /sys
4.0K    /local
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /selinux
4.0K    /srv
7.3M    /etc
8.0K    /tmp
8.1M    /bin
8.6G    /var
9.7M    /sbin
12K     /dev
16K     /lost+found
17M     /root
21M     /lib64
24K     /run
26M     /home
49M     /boot
59M     /opt
122M    /lib
858M    /usr
```

Comment: What are you running? Some services can lockup disk space while running, but are not actually using to store any permanent data.

Comment: I'm running Amazon linux with mysql on the instance rather than RDS. Once I free up the 50G it takes about 2-3 weeks to fill back up completely.

Comment: Does the disk space also clear up if you were to just restart the mysql service? Mysql should not be exhibiting the behavior you describe. It should only use disk space needed to store the data and temporarily to handle certain queries.

Comment: your question is not even valid, #1 ephemeral storage means it is gone once you reboot the machine. probably not what you want for a db box. #2 you should probably add a `-r` to your `sort` command

Comment: @datasage Restarting mysql does not clear up space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with ephemeral storage. It was that httpd wasn't restarting after logrotate.